# mergesort beginner question

Tags: algorithm

I now have a question on Mergesort algorithm.Because in the original algorithm,the list to be sorted is diveded into two sublists and sort recursively.
Now how about I want to divide the list of lengh n into 3 sub-lists of lengh n/3,and then sort these three sublists recursively and then combine?
I just simply modify the original algorithm by replacing everwhere 2 into a 3,wondered if that makes sense.

How about make it more general?Can we divide the lists into K sublists and sort them and combine?

Thank you for sharing your ideas for me.

Comment: You can surely do that. Unfortunately, it wouldn't help speed things up any better. Refer to Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest's book -- IIRC they have this analysis. Even better would be to actually formulate the recursion and prove why they wouldn't be any better.

Comment: You can divide into 3 lists, but merging them together becomes more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have n (n > 2) lists, it is not true that you need to carry out (n-1) comparisons on every merging step. However, the implementation becomes more complex.

Suppose you have three lists, `list[0..2]`, and assume for simplicity you are merging them and they are all still non-empty (i.e. you have not run to the end of any of the lists). Assume furthermore for simplicity that all elements are distinct, i.e. when you compare two elements they are never the same. You have then six possible "states" in which you can be, which correspond to the six permutations of the three lists in an increasing order of the first elements on the lists, i.e. if

```
list[0] = [5, 7, 11, 15]
list[1] = [3, 4, 20, 21]
list[2] = [9, 10, 12, 19]
```

then the corresponding permutation of the lists is [1, 0, 2], i.e. `list[1]` has the least front element and `list[2]` has the greatest front element.

When you now pop the next element (4) from `list[1]` you know already that `list[0].front` < `list[2].front` based on the state [1, 0, 2] where you were. So now you need to perform either 1 or 2 comparisons:

```
if (list[1].front < list[0].front) // (A)
   --> move to state [1, 0, 2], next to pop is list[1]
else if (list[1].front < list[2].front)
   --> move to state[0, 1, 2], next to pop is list[0]
else
   --> move state[0, 2, 1], next to pop is list[0]
```

Assuming some kind of uniformity, the probability that the comparison (A) returns true, i.e. that the next element on the list from which you removed the previous element is less than the least element on the other two lists, is 1/3, so you have on the average (1/3 x 1 + 2/3 x 2) = 5/3 comparisons instead of 2 (which would be n-1).

This is obviously worse by 2/3 comparisons per insert the normal mergesort which only needs 1 comparison per popped element.

We can get a better result by considering also partially ordered states. There are three distinct comparisons which can be made (list[0] -- list[1], list[1] -- list[2] and list[0] -- list[2]). If we allow for the known results (<, >) to be augmented with "don't know" (?), there are the following possible states:

```
0/1  1/2  0/2
  <    <    <   (total order) [0,1,2]
  <    ?    <   (0 is least but don't know if 1 < 2) [0,1,2] [0,2,1]
  <    ?    ?   (0 is < 1, but 2 can't be positioned) [2,0,1] [0,2,1] [0,1,2]
  ?    ?    ?   (no information about ordering) (all six permutations)
```

and then all the variants regarding permutations and swapping < for > at different places in the matrix.

Now if were in a (<,<,<) state (assume [0,1,2]) and you read the next element from the list from which you popped the previous one, there are two cases: either (1) you get an element that is lower than the element on list[1], in which case you are back at state [0,1,2] in one comparison; or you get an element that is higher than the element on list[1]. In this case you can output list[1] next, and you have entered a (<,?,<) state: you know that list[1] has the least front element but don't know now if list[0] or list[2] is the next.

Now in a (<,?,<) state you read a new element from list[1], you can use 1 + (1/3 + 4/3) = 1 5/3 comparisons to find the actual permutation of all the lists and you get back to a (<,<,<) state. Thus this sequence of two pushes cost 2 5/3 comparisons, for an average of 1 5/6 = 11/6 per insert; however because of the possibility that you can insert two lowest elements in a sequence from the same list the average cost is even less, by the same argument as before it is (1/3 + 2/3 x 11/6) = 6/18 + 22/18 = 1 + 5/9, worse than the original mergesort by 5/9 comparisons per insert but slightly better than 2/3 above.

For completeness, here the algorithm (fragment shown):

```
state_1_lt_2: /* known list[1].front < list[2].front */
  if (list[0].front < list[1].front):
    merge_from(0)
    goto state_1_lt_2 /* 1 insert 1 comp prob 1/3 */
  else
    merge_from(1)
    if (list[0].front < list[1].front)
      if (list[1].front < list[2].front)
        merge_from(0)
        goto state_1_lt_2 /* 2 inserts 3 comps prob 2/3*1/2*1/3 = 1/9 */
      else if (list[0].front < list[2].front)
        merge_from(0)
        goto state_2_lt_1 /* 2 inserts 4 comps prob 2/3*1/2*2/3*1/2 = 1/9 */
      else
        merge_from(2)
        goto state_0_lt_1 /* 2 inserts 4 comps prob 1/9 */
    else if (list[2].front < list[1].front)
      merge_from(2)
      goto state_1_lt_0 /* 2 inserts 3 comps 2/3 x 1/2 x 1/3 = 1/9 */
    else if (list[2].front < list[0].front)
      merge_from(1)
      goto state_2_lt_0 /* 2 inserts 4 comps prob 1/9 */
    else
      merge_from(1)
      goto state_0_lt_2 /* 2 inserts 4 comps prob 1/9 */
```

This sums up to an expected number of comparisons per insert of

```
1/3 x 1 + 4/9 x (4/2) + 2/9 x (3/2) = 6/18 + 16/18 + 6/18 = 30/18 = 1 5/9.
```

Comment: could you possibly have some links in implementing this? Because I have something like this as an assignment and I would like to find out as much as I can about it but I have searched google and found nothing about a mergesort with 3 partitions

Answer (score 4):

The problem with that approach is that is harder to merge 3 lists than 2 lists. With 2 lists you have only one comparison to do (current element) while with 3 lists you have to do at least two comparisons (always n-1).

The power of merge sort is the merging. Therefore your idea will be not working efficiently. For parallel sorting there are other specialised algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

The merging algorithm works on two lists. Unless you somehow adapt the merging algorithm to work on three lists simultaneously, in a way that's "better" than merging list 1 with list 2, then with list 3 (effectively two merging operations), doing partition-by-three method is not going to give better results.

Answer (score 1):

if you merge sort n elements usual way there is Log(n)/Log(2)*1*n comparisons, but if you split by k instead of 2, there is aprox Log(n)/Log(k) merges and ceil(log2(k!)) comparisons on each merging. That mean that by splitting by k you will get

```
nc=Log(2)/Log(k)*ceil(log2(k!))
```

for k=3 is increase by 1.26
for k=13 -> nc = 9.188 (13 numbers cant be sorted in less than 34 comparisons)