# 3 partition mergesort

Tags: arrays, quicksort, mergesort

My professor assigned my class with implementing mergesort in arrays with 3-part partitioning and merging.

That was the exact question from the professor. Problem is I have found no such thing as a 3-way mergesort I only know of a 3-way quicksort so I thought that he probably meant to take an array, split it into 3 parts and then mergesort those 3 parts together and I'm doing this by mergesorting the first 2 parts together and then mergesorting the combined part with the 3rd part.

Did I think correctly and did I do the right thing (already implemented but I'm not posting the code since it doesn't have anything to do with my question) or have I understood wrong and there is something like a 3-way mergesort that I am not aware of.

The professor tends to give us assignments that have to do with stuff that we have not learned yet that's why I'm so sceptical about this and I looked as much as I could in Google etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you mergesorted the three sub arrays, you can merge them together in one go: compare the first elements of all three and place the smallest into the combined array, then take the next element from the array you took the smallest from and do the compariosn again until all subarray elements are accounted for.

Make sure you hande the case where there are only two elements in the array (so you cannot partition it into three non-empty parts).  Also, in the above paragraph, one array will be empty before the others when merging, so you need to account for that too.

Comment: I actually use the Arrays.sort for each one of the three and then I merge them in pairs as I said. As for what you told me to do I figured I could do it in one go but it seemed too complicated for me that's why I did it in two steps whereas the first step returned the merged array of the first 2 parts. As to my main question am I actually doing it right or is there a way to implement a 3-way mergesort that has nothing to do with what I described doing?

Comment: IF you are calling `Arrays.sort()` to do the sorting, then you are not doing merge-sort (unless that call is doing that, which is not guaranteed).  Merge-sort is a recursive function (calling itself recursively to sort the smaller arrays) as you describe it in your second paragraph.  Sure you can do the merging 2 arrays at a time, but if you merge all three at once, you get some performance benefits

Comment: So you say that after I have the 3 sub arrays, I should mergesort each one of them individually and as a last step I should mergesort the 3 parts all at once or could he maybe be asking something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224492/mergesort-beginner-question . By the way he still hasn't answered

Comment: Yes, what I described is the same as the link you list provided

Comment: I'm actually trying to find more resources about this kind of mergesort but I can't seem to find anything about it, is there a possibility you know what to look for in Google for example. Googling 3-way mergesort or mergesort with 3 partitions definitely does not provide anything at all

Comment: What part of the algorithm do you need more research on?

Comment: anything would do. About the splitting into 3 parts I found some criteria to do that but the problem is those criteria were about splitting the array in 3 parts only once so I believe that even my splitting wouldn't work right now. But the hardest part would definitely be the merging, that's my main problem I would say

Comment: If you can split correctly once, you will do the splitting again when you recurse.  For the merging, you need to compare three numbers (the current elements of the three sorted arrays) and decide which is smallest, put that in the result array, advance to the next element in the sorted array the min came from, then repeat until you run out of elements in one of the arrays; at which point you have only two arrays to merge (thus two numbers to compare at a time) just like in regular (2-way) merge-sort.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a three part merge sort, because thats what it does.
Take a look at http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Arrays/Merge.htm