# Merge sort in c++ with divide 3

Tags: sorting, mergesort

How can I write a merge sort **but divide to 3**?

```
int merge_sort(int input[], int p, int r)
{
    if ( p >= r )
        return 0; 

    int mid = floor((p + r) / 2);
    merge_sort(input, p, mid);
    **merge_sort(input, mid + 1, r);** 
    merge(input, p, r);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3 partition mergesort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667884/3-partition-mergesort)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably supposed to be a 3 way merge. You may want to consider using a [bottom up merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation). For either top down or bottom up merge, most of the complexity is going to be in the merge function. As mentioned in the answer linked to by zwergmaster, it's a 3 way merge of runs. Each run needs a current and ending index or pointer. A sequence of if / else statements end up doing two compares to determine which of 3 runs has the smallest element, and then that smallest element is moved to the destination array (or vector or ...) and the next element from that run is retrieved. When the end of one of the 3 runs is reached, the code switches into a 2 way merge. When the end of the next run is reached, the code copies the rest of the remaining run. Then the next set of 3 runs are merged, repeating the process until the end of the array is reached, which could happen within any of the 3 runs, so the last merge near the end of the array may be a merge of 3 or 2 runs, or just a copy of 1 run.

It would be more efficient to have an initial function that allocates a temp array the same size as the array to be sorted, then have it call the merge sort function passing the temp array as a parameter, rather than constantly allocating and freeing small temp arrays during the merge sort process.

So using top down merge sort partial code to help explain this:

```
merge_sort(int *a, int n)
{
    int *b = new int[n];
    top_down_merge_sort(a, b, 0, n);
    /* ... */
    delete[] b;
}

top_down_merge_sort(int *a, int *b, int beg, int end)
{
    if(end - beg < 3){
        /* sort in place */
        return;
    }
    int run0 = beg;
    int run1 = beg +   (end-beg)/3;
    int run2 = beg + 2*(end-beg)/3;
    top_down_merge_sort(a, b, run0, run1);
    top_down_merge_sort(a, b, run1, run2);
    top_down_merge_sort(a, b, run2, end);
    merge_runs(a, b, run0, run1, run2, end);
}
```